# Rewrite Code Form Callback to Async Await

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have been trying to convert my existing Express JS code from function callback to  Async Await. 
The function callback code is

```
app.get('/contactlist', (req, res) => {
  db.contactlist.find((err, docs) => {
    res.json(docs);
  });
});
```

And the Async Await code is

```
app.get('/contactlist', async (req, res) => {
  db.contactlist.find(async(err, docs) => {
    res.json(await docs);
  });
});
```

The new code works good and I have strong feeling that, it is not the right Implementation of Async Await

Answer (score 3):

You're still using callbacks. You can only switch to `async/await`, if the API returns promises. `app.get()` does not return promises, so the following doesn't work with Express:

```
let (req, res) = await app.get('/contactlist');
try {
 let docs = await db.contactlist.find();
 res.json(docs);
} catch (err) {
  // Handle the error 
}
```

All of that would have to be inside an `async` function.

What is `db` in your example? If `db.contactlist.find` returns a promise, you can use `async/await` like this:

```
app.get('/contactlist', async (req, res) => {
  try {
   let docs = await db.contactlist.find();
   res.json(docs);
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle the error 
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you @user835611 I realised the same a bit late after I posted the question,  that is the duty of the Express API to return promise and that is currently not done. Let say the Express API do return promises, in that case the code would be rewritten to have `.then` implemented in my code?

Answer (score 0):

you did not convert the callback to async await at all,callback is still there.The right implementation would look like this

```
    app.get('/contactlist', async (req, res) => {
    const docs = await getContactList();
    res.json(docs)
});

function getContactList() {
    let promise = new promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        db.contactlist.find({}, function(err, results) {
            if (err)
                reject(err)
            else
                resolve(results)

        });
    });
    return promise
}
```

^EDITS: Here's the complete example, if you have a custom function against await, you can promisify that function by creating and returning a promise in that function

Comment: No it will not work, as we are not creating a Async function we are using a already created API function  `db.contactlist.find();`, which a mongojs API and this mongojs API does not return a promise.

Comment: @user5740953 You will need to promisify all callback based functions

Comment: @itsundefined can you please give an example.